# Exporting Excel tabs into Powerpoint Slides based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

hope you can help.

Complete novice in VBA and I've searched and searched for an answer to my question but cannot find what I'm looking for.

What I have is a workbook with numerous tabs which hold different data and narrative. I need some way to to export these sheets (print view area) into separate PowerPoint slides only if cell "CI8" of those tabs are greater than 0. For example, I have tabs called "RestWest" "RestCentre" "RestEast" "RestRS" and if only RestWest and RestRS have their cell CI8 >0, only those two sheets would pull into Powerpoint. Pasting as a picture would be best.

I have been able to do it to export into PDF but senior management like PowerPoint better.

Hope you can help and give me some pointers.

Thanks for your time

Should have included the following code as it pulls a single sheet into PowerPoint but need to include the cell value criteria

```
Sub CopyRangeToPresentation()

    Dim pp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim SlideTitle As String
    Set pp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    PPSlide.Select
    Sheets("RestWest").Range("A1:CV77").CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    SlideTitle = "My First PowerPoint Slide"
    PPSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You won't find any ready to use code for that. But if I google for *"excel vba copy paste  range to powerpoint"* I find many results how this can be achieved in general. Use one of this tutorials to start something on your own. If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question to it. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks, I should have included that I have a code which copies a single sheet into powerpoint. Included in my original post now.

Comment: Just check the value with `If Worksheets("RestWest").Range("CI8").Value > 0 Then` put your copy/paste to PowerPoint here and end with an `End If`.

Answer (score 2):

[TheSpreadsheetGuru - Copy & Paste An Excel Range Into PowerPoint With VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba)

I'm very novice also, but check out this link and maybe try something like:

```
For Each sht In Worksheets
With sht
    If .Range("CI8").Value2 > 0 Then
        .Range("Print_Area").Copy
        'use SpreadSheetGuru to show you how to insert new slide and paste
        ' ...
    End If
End With
Next
```